# Given a square inscribed in a right triangle find the length of the hypotenuse

Tags: geometry

> If $ABCD$ is a square, $OEF$ is a right triangle, $OA = 48$, and $OB = 36$, what
>   is the length of the segment $EF$?

[image]

Well first I found that the length of a side of a square is $60$ by the Pythagorean theorem. Then I also get a lot of similar triangles such as $\triangle FOE \sim \triangle FDA$, $\triangle FOE \sim \triangle BC$E, $\triangle FDA \sim \triangle BCE$

I know that $FE= 60+FD+CE$ so I just need to find a way to relate what I know to $FD$ and $CE$. It seems straight forward but I just keep going in circles any help would be appreciated or if you know of a simpler approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

Use $$\triangle FDA \sim \triangle AOB$$
 to find
$\frac{FD}{DA}$ and also use  $$\triangle ECB \sim \triangle BOA$$

to find $\frac{EC}{CB}$.